# Find Max By Rows for a 3-Dimensional Matrix without loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow2.0

I have an matrix with shape (2,4,4) and want to obtain max by rows for each matrix.

```
w = array([
       [[0.9695303 , 0.99844801, 0.99712014, 0.99493009],
        [0.99111579, 0.99997843, 0.99995245, 0.99998065],
        [0.99940958, 0.99998028, 0.99999291, 0.99996183],
        [0.99701626, 0.99997955, 0.99998736, 0.99998028]],

       [[0.99992947, 0.99999852, 0.99988576, 0.99975061],
        [0.99999059, 1.        , 0.99999982, 0.99999987],
        [0.99999622, 0.99999945, 0.99999837, 0.99999683],
        [0.99998404, 0.99999998, 0.99999842, 0.99999804]]
])
```

My desired output should be

```
[array([0.99844801, 0.99998065, 0.99999291, 0.99998736]),
 array([0.99999852, 1.        , 0.99999945, 0.99999998])]
```

The naive way is given below

```
max_by_row = []
for matrix in w:
  max_by_row.append(np.max(matrix,axis=1))

print(max_by_row)
```

Is there way to do the same without loops?

Comment: Why aren't you using `axis=2`?

Comment: It works. Thank you. I didn't expect axis could be assigned values other than 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
max_by_row = [np.max(matrix,axis=1) for matrix in w]
```

Comment: Not quite what i'm looking for .There is [amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) which we can specify axes as tuple of ints, and the maximum is selected over multiple axes, instead of a single axis.